# Установка драйверов на ноутбук lenovo в mac os

Tags: mac, драйвер

Как посмотреть недостающие драйвера и установить их на ноутбук в Mac OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы ставите хакинтош? И вероятно по какому-то руководству? В нём может быть дополнительная информация.

Посмотреть можно вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ок, я имею ввиду ещё то, что в виндовс допустим мы видим драйвера, которые нужно поставить для полноценной работы ноутбука. А как с этим в Хакинтош быть?

Comment: @Sven основные драйвера идут в вместе с ОС. На внешние устройства вы ставите их сами. У вас не работает тачпад? (-:

Comment: А что вы имеете ввиду "на внешние устройства"? и как их ставить в маке на ноут?

Comment: @Sven например, 4g-модем. Драйвер качается из интернета в виде *.dmg пакета, открывается и устанавливается (-:

Comment: @Sven лучше уточните, что не работает у вас.

Comment: ну пока вроде всё работает. Я просто хотел узнать для сравнения с Windows. При установки Windows, например,  в диспетчере устройств видны драйвера, которые надо поставить, а как в Mac хотел узнать сразу. Т.е. в принципе с установкой Мака, а точнее Хакинтоша, ноутбук должен работать без глюков я так понимаю без поиска дополнительных драйверов..

Comment: @Sven всё верно (-: А диспетчер задач в маке я показал на скриншоте

Comment: ок, ясно, спасибо!=)